# Should I write "to thanks us" or "thanks to us" in the following sentence?

Tags: idioms, infinitive-clauses

> As previously agreed, **to thanks us** for our detective work, Mr. Cotard
>   provided us with free accommodation.
>
> As previously agreed, **thanks to us** for our detective work, Mr. Cotard
>   provided us with free accommodation.

What's the correct form? And why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the first example possibility should be "to thank us." "To thank" is an infinitive, which takes the root form of the verb.

**The second version is correct.**

Each of the two phrasings has a subtly different meaning.

> As previously agreed, thanks to us <strike>for our detective work</strike>, Mr. Cotard provided us with free accommodation.

In this version of the sentence, `thanks to X` presents X as the **ultimate reason** why the entire arrangement was made or the agent responsible for it.

The `thanks to X` construction should only modify one thing, which is the thing explained. The strikeout eliminates what would have been an extraneous recipient of the modification, had this been the sentence you intended. See [Wiktionary's definition of "thanks to"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/thanks_to) for further clarification.

> As previously agreed, to thank us for our detective work, Mr. Cotard provided us with free accommodation.

In this version of the sentence, `to thank us` expresses the **intent** behind some event, namely the event that follows.

I believe this is the more correct form because it seems to express your intended meaning.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I confused the phrase "thank to us", "thanks to us", and "to thank us". Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The correct phrase here is **to thank us** meaning *in order to show us his appreciation for our detective work*. Here **to** means **для того, чтобы ...** *in order to...* so you need the form plain form of the verb: **thank**.